# ViewPager inside NestedScrollView inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have created and xml file like:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout/>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="CustomScrollingBehavior">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
           <TableLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
           <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="CustomScrollingBehavior"/>
       <LinearLayout/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView/>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout/>
```

ViewPager has `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`and each fragment has a `RecyclerView` insdie. Everything is working fine except when loading content the first Fragment of the ViewPager has scrolling issue.

When I scroll first Fragment it gets stuck and does not scroll after the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed completely. But after waiting for 2-3 seconds or switching to another fragment inside ViewPager and scrolling, it starts scrolling normally.

If anyone else has come across this problem please help me.

Comment: can I ask what's your CustomScrollingBehavior? I'm also trying the same layout but I want the tablayout to stick below the toolbar and scroll the viewpager